# How to I Optimize Response of PHP Code

Tags: php

I have a Code to Rebuild Image in PHP but they work Slowly
This is [Demo URL of Image](http://uplaytube.com/vi/AJ-7X6cvOhY/mqdefault.jpg)

and Original URL is Work Very Fastly [Original URL of Image](http://ytimg.googleusercontent.com/vi/AJ-7X6cvOhY/mqdefault.jpg)

I'm try this Code for Rebuild Image with my Own Custom URL

```
<?php

if(!isset($_GET['v']))      
exit('VIDEO ID IS NOT EXIST');  
$v = $_GET['v'];
$fmt = $_GET['fmt'];
$url = 'http://ytimg.googleusercontent.com/vi/'.$v.'/'.$fmt;
$data = file_get_contents ($url);
Header ("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $data;

?>
```

but this code is work very slowly Image loading is Slow how can i optimized image response fastly

Comment: For me both is fast. BTW never use user params without validating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a little faster than using `file_get_contents`.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['v'])) exit('VIDEO ID IS NOT EXIST');  
Header ("Content-type: image/jpeg");
readfile("http://ytimg.googleusercontent.com/vi/{$_GET['v']}/{$_GET['fmt']}");
```

Comment: sir can you make full code I can't understand sorry to say I'm beginner.

Answer (score 0):

The remote webs server closes the connection aftr 15 seconds and until then, it keeps alive.
So the solution for this is to tell server to close the connection after every request.
This may solve your issue.

```
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header'=>'Connection: close\r\n')));
file_get_contents($url,false,$context);
```

Comment: watch your syntax. got an extra `)`